# What is the difference between I-V characteristics of rectifier diodes and Schottky diodes?

Tags: diodes, device-characteristics

I searched for the difference between rectifier diodes and Schottky diodes on the internet but cannot find it.

Comment: What google search terms did you use?

Comment: Schottky diodes are also rectifier diodes, so no difference. There are also other types of rectifier diodes. The difference is that what subtype type of rectifier diode it is. Wikipedia article on diodes should cover that.

Comment: i live in iran and my english language is intermediate
i search it with own language but not found 
Andy aka

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes you mean pn diodes by "rectifier diodes"; Schottkys are considered rectifiers as well. Diodes not generally considered rectifiers (but still usable as such) would be Zener diodes, LEDs, photodiodes, varactors, and TVS diodes, among others. PN, PIN, and Schottky diodes are all types of rectifier.

Both types of diodes (if sufficiently idealized) follow the same ideal diode equation, just with slightly different numbers involved.

Schottky diodes have a substantially lower forward voltage than pn diodes. For silicon, Schottky diodes can have forward voltages in the 0.3 to 0.5 V range, compared to the 0.7 to 1.0 V range for pn diodes. For silicon carbide, Schottky diodes have a typical forward voltage of around 1.0 to 1.5 V, compared to pn junctions of typically 3.0 to 4.0 V. (SiC pn diodes are not commercially manufactured, primarily for this reason.)

Schottky diodes are *significantly* leakier than pn diodes; their reverse current is typically a few orders of magnitude higher, μA compared to nA.

---

Outside the I-V curve, Schottky diodes also have much faster (ideally 0) reverse recovery time, while pn diodes can have a reverse recovery time measured in the tens or hundreds of μs (except for FREDs, which are typically in the tens of ns).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the specified Vf point. Schottky diodes have lower forward voltage at a specified current than a similarly rated PN diode. Practically, move the i-v curve a bit to the left.

Comment: thanks for you. and what is difference between Characteristic equation of those?